# The same code running with Mac Clang but crashes with Unix GCC

Tags: c++, string, debugging

I have a bizarre issue for code that I am running; The difficulty is that its not mine and its 
quite a sizable code with various functions and headers,

quick fact

1.) Runs on my Mac machine compiler: Apple clang version 11.0.0

2.) Crashes on my Unix machine with gcc 6.3.0 or higher

---

Debugging:

Using the gdb tool the crash happens on a simple line std::string line="";
With error:
   "reporting free(): **invalid next size (normal):...**;"

---

As I said the code is huge but let me try to give some specifics. This happens in a function

```
void read_data(std::string filename, number_type & impact_parameter, number_type &    n_participants, number_type & multiplicity){

        std::ifstream infile(filename);
        std::string line="";

        size_type counter_numbers = 0;
        size_type counter_lines = 0;
        while (infile)
        {
            std::getline(infile, line); // Read in current line
            and so on...
```

The files that are read are of format:

```
# event 0
# b     = 10.63639744
# npart = 95
and so on...
```

It will read through the second line 
    current = 10.63639744 then going on next line it crashes,

```
*** Error in `./MultB': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000001fb9760 ***
```

I would really appreciate some help on this. Is this a compiler issue (Macchiato's vs Unix) or something can be done with this,

thanks, Damir

--------------- Update-------------------

It seems the gdb didn't help much to locate the memory bug in the code; 
I chopped up the code to what fraction of the code would work.

Again, not being able to post the complete code (comprised of many headers and function) it appears the code would actually not have the "heap issue" if in the main class I dismiss initialization of some member variables /* stuff*/,

```
public:
 .
 .
 , r_interpolators_(0)
 , r_splines_(0)
 , racc_(0)
 , Nm_(128)
 , Nr_(size_type(grid_max/grid_step))
 , W_interpolators_(0)
 , W_splines_(0)
 , W_acc_(0)
 , normalizations_(0)
 /*{
            // initialize grid sites
            std::cout<<"GRID SIZE = "<<grid_size_<<std::endl;
            x_sites_ = new number_type[grid_size_];
            y_sites_ = new number_type[grid_size_];
            r_sites_ = new number_type[Nr_];
            R_ = grid_max_ - grid_step_;
            for (size_type i = 0; i < grid_size_; ++i)
            {
                    x_sites_[i] = x_from_index(i);
                    y_sites_[i] = -y_from_index(i);
                    r_sites_[i] = R_ * i / Nr_;

            }


    }*/

    {}
    ~Collision(){}
```

I added empty brackets and deconstructor; This will not report heap memory issue. Perhaps an idea why the "x_sites, y_sites" are not cleaned up by the deconstructor?

Comment: By itself, `std::string line="";` should not crash the program (unless maybe you are totally out of memory). I would guess the heap is being corrupted somewhere else.

Comment: Most likely, the memory heap has become corrupted at some point before this. It's pretty much impossible to guess how or where it happened – you need to work your way backwards.

Comment: Just because code *compiles* and *runs*, in *no way* means that it is *valid* code with well defined behaviour. My first step would be to try a build with Address Sanitizer enabled - it's pretty good at spotting weird memory related bugs.

Comment: Not enough info to help. But sine you are using clang/gcc I recommend use of address sanitizer. Just build your app with flag: `-fsanitize=address` and then run application. This will catch memory issue which causes this crash.

Comment: Learn more about *undefined behavior*. Consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)

Answer (score 0):

since your code wont reproduce the problem, and the line it reports crashing it, it pretty much can't be crashing on... there are a few things to look at:

1) Do you have a different prototype than declaration?

A lot of times where you have a crash that can't be possible it is because the calling code and the called code have a different expectation about what elements are laid out in the preamble to the call.

for instance:

```
`int func(long long param, int param2)`
```

and

```
`int func(double param, int param2)`
```

will start at a different offset and expect local variable to be at a different offset so if one is in the .h and one is in the .cpp then bad things will happen.

2) `std::ifstream infile(filename);` is borked somehow.

Comment: actually my example is probably not valid on x86_64, the abi would put them in different 64bit registers as per the calling convention, but would be an issue in a calling convention that put them on the stack, or if one of them were something like a struct that has a data storage type that would go on the stack rather than a register, just an example - let me change one to a double, which would change which register it went into.

Comment: This is actually very odd; It seems I cannot find the function "infile(filename)", and when I step in with gdb into "read_data(...)" it skips the line std::ifstream infile(filename) onto the next one?!

Comment: That line is not a call.  It is initializing local variable `infile`.

Comment: @stark below the level of C the calling function saves registers, copies values to registers for params, sometimes also to the stack depending on the type then will jump to the subroutine (done different ways in different ABI's)... so I mean whatever is calling that function may not agree about the definition, because the prototype is wrong.

Comment: @damir that is consistent with the prototype being wrong... what is your function prototype that is visible to the calling code.

Comment: Line "infile" is a local variable; From c++ documentation this seems like a valid syntax---->std::ifstream ifs ("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);

Comment: @damir yeah, local variables get created on the stack... if the calling code and the function itself disagree on what address the local address start on, this sort of thing happens... your computer doesn’t know or run C++. It runs object code that is a representation of that code, when the debugger can not hit a line for some reason that usually means that something is inconsistent in that translation, dirty build or different parts of object code are built with different expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, @Marek R was right on the money. Including the command  -fsanitize=address when compiling the code locates exactly where the heap-buffer-overflow happens. Here's a piece of the output,

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow auxiliary/collision.hpp:84 in Collision<double>::Collision(double, double)
```

Then looking at the collision class which I posted in the question,

```
        x_sites_ = new number_type[grid_size_];
        y_sites_ = new number_type[grid_size_];
        r_sites_ = new number_type[Nr_];
        R_ = grid_max_ - grid_step_;
        for (size_type i = 0; i < grid_size_; ++i)
        {
                x_sites_[i] = x_from_index(i);
                y_sites_[i] = -y_from_index(i);
                r_sites_[i] = R_ * i / Nr_; // line 84
        }
```

Simply, dynamical array "r_sites_" has a smaller size (N_r) then "x(y)*sites*" (grid_size_) even though being in the same loop,

cheers, Damir